# SKSpriteNode erratic swipe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uiswipegesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

**I have created the following sprite kit node :**

```
SKSpriteNode *megadeth;
megadeth = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"megadeth_rocks.png"];
megadeth.name = @"awesome";
```

**and added the swipe gesture as follows:**

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizerUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeUp:)];
recognizerUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizerUp];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizerDn = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeDn:)];
recognizerDn.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizerDn];
}

- (void)handleSwipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{

     NSLog(@"Node Swiped Up");
     if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
       {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
        touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];
        SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];
        if([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"awesome"]){
        NSLog(@"Perform Action on AWESOME node");
        SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:(0-touchedNode.position.y) duration:0.5];
        SKAction *fade = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.25];
        //SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, fade]];
        [touchedNode runAction:sequence];
      }
    }
}
```

When I swipe the node, its swiping but it comes back to its original position and then fades to remove.

What I want is that when I swipe, it should move to the swiped position and remove. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: You should use the `locationInNode:` method instead of `locationInView:` in an SKScene. Then you dont need to convert the point as well.

Comment: @ZeMoon I am using locationInNode in touchesBegan method. The gestureRecognizer Method only handles location in view

Comment: The problem lies with the `[SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:(0-touchedNode.position.y) duration:0.5]`

Comment: What is the effect you are trying to achieve>

Comment: @ZeMoon simply swipe the node up/down and while its about to reach the end, its fades away....in short swipe to remove...

Comment: @ZeMoon should I draw a bezier path instead ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73037/discussion-between-madlokesh-and-zemoon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of `[SKAction moveByX:y:]` , I used `[SKAction moveToY:duration:]` which made everything work like charm**

**Here's the updated `handleSwipeUp:` method:**

```
- (void)handleSwipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{

 NSLog(@"Node Swiped Up");
 //if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
   //{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
    touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];
    SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];
    if([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"awesome"]){
    NSLog(@"Perform Action on AWESOME node");
    **SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveToY:(touchedNode.position.y+200) duration:0.5];**
    //SKAction *fade = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.25];
    SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, remove]];
    [touchedNode runAction:sequence];
  }
//}
```

}

Hope this helps !!!